# Toggle button value in controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7 and PHP 7.4.

I have a form containing 20 fields. I' m trying to implement the toggle button for one of my fields. My logic is pretty simple. I've a hidden input fields to grab the value for clicked toggle. It works fine but when I tried to pass the toggle values to my controller using ajax, it gives me an error like

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Might be, the method of calling ajax is improper.
How can I get my toggle values into my controller?

Blade

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('form_for_private_sellers')}}">
    <div class="select form-group">
        <input type="number" name="mileage" placeholder="10,000 (☒km - ☐Mi)" class="value-input" />
        <input type="hidden" class="currency-input" />
              
    <div class="currency-list switch">
         <input type="checkbox" data-width="100%" class="input-lg" name="mileage" id="mileage" checked />
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_mileage" id="hidden_mileage" value="km" />
   </div>
</div>

</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#mileage').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'km',
    off: 'miles',
    onstyle: 'success',
    offstyle: 'success',
});

$('#mileage').change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
      var km =  $('#hidden_mileage').val('km');
    }
    else
    {
      var miles =  $('#hidden_mileage').val('miles');
    }

        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('form_for_private_sellers') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:{_token:_token,km:km,miles:miles},
            success:function(data){
                if(data == 'done')
                {
                    console.log('hello');
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Controller

```
public function process_private_sellers(Request $request)
{

    $mile = $request->get('miles');
    dd($mile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If this is best approach to go with or not. But I updated the ajax call with **serialize()** and my issue is resolved

```
var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
var form_data = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('form_for_private_sellers') }}",
    method:"POST",
    data:{_token:_token,form_data:form_data},
    success:function(data){
        if(data == 'done')
        {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    }
});
```